# Como puedo centrar componentes en java swing usando GridBagLayout?

Tags: java, java-swing, eclipse

Tengo un JPanel independiente que luego necesito acoplar a mi JFrame. Necesito que los componentes de mi JPanel esten centrados pero no encuentro la forma. Muestro imágenes:

Así es como se ve actualmente:
[image: Asi es como me queda la imagen actualmente]

Así es como quisiera que se viera:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los 2 botones centrados.

En esa ventana, tengo definido el JFrame por un lado y el panel que muestra todos esos botones por otro, ya que el panel principal va a ir cambiando.

Mi JPanel tiene un BorderLayout, en la posición South le agregué el botón de Salir y en el Center va el GridBagLayout que necesito centrar sus componentes.
En principio solo necesito centrar esos 2 botones.

Mi idea fue colocar JLabel vacíos (sin texto) con constraint en weightx = 0.5 y weighty=0.5 en diagonal (como si fuesen las esquinass de un cuadrado, dejando entre medio los 2 botones), de esta forma conseguí centrar los botones pero, es útil cuando la distribución es simétrica.

Mi pregunta es, hay alguna forma mas prolija de centrar las cosas? Ya que la mía dificilmente se adapte a cambios donde la imagen ya no es tan simétrica como esos 2 botones.
Quizá no hace falta usar GridBagLayout y yo no sé. Alguna recomendación?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes aplicar el layout GridBagLayout para centrar uno o más componentes.

#### Centrar un componente

```
panel.setLayout( new GridBagLayout() );
panel.add(new JButton("Acción 1"), new GridBagConstraints());
```

Relacionado: [Java GUI - How to center a single button](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41404769/18473608)

#### Centrar dos o más componentes

```
panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
gridBagConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
gridBagConstraints.gridy = 0; // primer elemento tiene y = 0
gridBagConstraints.weightx = 0.4;
gridBagConstraints.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
panel.add(new JButton("Acción 1"), gridBagConstraints);
gridBagConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
gridBagConstraints.gridy = 1; // segundo elemento tiene y = 1
gridBagConstraints.weightx = 0.4;
gridBagConstraints.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
panel.add(new JButton("Acción 2"), gridBagConstraints);
```

Relacionado: [How do I center JButtons (Main menu) in a frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22995579/18473608)

[image: Resultado final]